# /usr/bin/dpkg: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/dpkg: undefined symbol: setexecfilecon

Tags: apt, dpkg

`enter code here`I am trying to install the package `libnl-3-dev`.

command used : `sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev`

```
xxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.27) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
 liblzma-dev : Depends: liblzma5 (= 5.2.2-1.3) but 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libtirpc1 : Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.4 is to be installed
 nfs-common : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97) but 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Depends: libevent-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.4 is to be installed
              Depends: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.5.9) but 1.5.6-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

To resolve this I tried the command :`sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`.

```
xxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libblas-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcupti-doc
  libftdi1 libgfortran-4.8-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0
  libhttp-parser2.1 libjbig-dev libpcrecpp0 libprotobuf-lite8 libpython3.5
  libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libssh2-1 libssl-doc
  libstd-rust-1.30 libstd-rust-1.31 libstd-rust-dev libtiffxx5 libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev python3.5 python3.5-minimal rust-gdb x11proto-composite-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-plugin-dev gcc-6-base gcc-9-base libasan0
  libatomic1 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libgcc-4.8-dev libgfortran-4.8-dev libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
  libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 libmpfr-dev libmpfr4 libpython3.4
  libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal
  libpython3.5-stdlib libquadmath0 libstd-rust-1.31 libstdc++6 libtsan0
  python3.4 python3.4-minimal python3.4-venv python3.5 python3.5-minimal
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.8-locales xpp cups-pdf gcc-4.8-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  libmpfr-doc python3.4-doc python3.5-venv python3.5-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups build-essential cargo comerr-dev cups g++ g++-4.6
  g++-4.6-multilib g++-4.8 g++-4.8-multilib g++-multilib gcc-4.6-multilib
  gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-multilib gfortran gfortran-4.8 hplip indicator-printers
  krb5-multidev language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
  language-pack-gnome-en-base lib32asan0 lib32atomic1 lib32bz2-1.0
  lib32gcc-4.8-dev lib32gcc1 lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32ncurses5
  lib32ncurses5-dev lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++-4.8-dev lib32stdc++6
  lib32tinfo-dev lib32tinfo5 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev libatk1.0-dev
  libatlas-base-dev libatlas-dev libboost-dev libboost1.54-dev libbz2-dev
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32
  libc6-i386 libc6-x32 libcairo2-dev libcuda1-384 libcupti-dev libcupti5.5
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev
  libftdi-dev libgcrypt11-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libgnutls-dev libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libkrb5-dev
  liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpng12-dev
  libprotobuf-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev libpython3-dev
  libpython3.4-dev libpython3.5-dev librtmp-dev libssl-dev libstdc++-4.8-dev
  libstdc++6-4.6-dev libtiff4-dev libtiff5-dev libtirpc1 libtool libusb-dev
  libx32asan0 libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-4.8-dev libx32gcc1 libx32gomp1
  libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 libx32stdc++-4.8-dev libx32stdc++6 libxft-dev
  locales nfs-common nfs-kernel-server nvidia-384 nvidia-opencl-icd-384
  printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-splix python-dev python2.7-dev python3-dev python3.4-dev
  python3.5-dev rpcbind rustc ubuntu-minimal zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-6-base gcc-9-base libisl15 libstd-rust-1.31
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.8 cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-plugin-dev libasan0 libatomic1 libcups2
  libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgfortran-4.8-dev libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgomp1
  libitm1 libmpfr-dev libmpfr4 libpython3.4 libpython3.4-minimal
  libpython3.4-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib
  libquadmath0 libstdc++6 libtsan0 python3.4 python3.4-minimal python3.4-venv
  python3.5 python3.5-minimal
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  libc-bin
39 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 118 to remove and 242 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/57.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 868 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] Yes, do as I say!
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

/usr/bin/dpkg: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/dpkg: undefined symbol: setexecfilecon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)
```

Now, this time i was encountered with the above error.

Can any one please help with this?

Comment: Use code formatting ("{}" button) to format the code in your message, so it becomes readable.

Comment: That is TOTALLY unreadable please fix.

Comment: @vanadium  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @David have fixed can you please look at the above error.

Comment: You will need to remove PPA's you added yourself. SOme appear not to be compatible with your current Ubuntu version.

Comment: @vanadium Hi, the system which i am using currently, is used by some other users previously.... how can i know  that, what are the PPA's added by user..                             i ran the command :  ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
the above command listed some of the PPA's, in that PPA's how can i know that which are the PPA's were installed by the previous users ??

Comment: In the graphical tool "Software and updates", you will see a tab "Other Software". These are PPA's. You can remove them there.

Comment: @vanadium i am working on VM. so, i cant go through GUI .. is there any alternative way to remove unusual PPA's ..